# How do you find the index of data in a linked list recursively using C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, indexof

Essentially, the list and element being searched for are passed to the function. The function should return the position of the element in the list. I've attached what I have tried. In the test program which has 11 elements by the time this function is called, 1 is always the result if the element is within the list, and it correctly returns -1, if it is not.

```
template <class T>
int getPosition(Node<T>* head, T element)
{
    int pos = 1;

    if (head == nullptr) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (head->data == element) {
        return pos;
    }
    return getPosition(head->next, element);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your pos value is always 1. Try this.

```
template <class T> int getPosition(Node<T>* head, T element, int pos = 0) {
    
    if (head == nullptr) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (head->data == element) {
        return pos;
    }  
  return getPosition(head->next, element, pos +1);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of your recursion is always 1 or -1 - you're missing a `+ 1`.

Since you're numbering from one:

- If the list is empty, the index is -1
- If the head contains the value you're looking for, the index is 1
- Otherwise, look for the value in the tail, and

  - If the value was found there, the index is one more than the index in the tail
  - If it wasn't found, the index is -1

Translated:

```
template <class T>
int getPosition(Node<T>* head, T element)
{
    if (head == nullptr) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (head->data == element) {
        return 1;
    }
    int tailPosition = getPosition(head->next, element);
    return tailPosition < 0 ? -1 : tailPosition + 1;
}
```